# Is there a scala list operation that makes tuples from lists?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, tuples

I'm trying to process triplets in a list.  Imperatively, I could do this:

```
for(i = 1; i < list.length-1; i++)
{
   process( list[i-1], list[i], list[i+1] )
}
```

Is there a List function in Scala (or how would one write it) that can do something like this:

```
val data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
val tuples = data.some_magic_func
tuples would be[(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (4,5,6) ... ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val data = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
val tuples = data.sliding(3).toList
// tuples would be List(List(1,2,3), List(2,3,4), List(3,4,5), List(4,5,6) ... )
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for.  Will mark as 'the answer' as soon as SO will allow it.

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: This is not correct, the result is `tuples: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4), ...`

Comment: As Landei already remarked, this answer is NOT correct, it doesn't give a list of tuples, but a list of lists. The question is clearly about list of tuples! Landei's solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 23):

Pablo's solution isn't entirely correct, you still need to transform the list of lists into a list of tuples:

```
val data = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
val tuples = data.sliding(3).toList.collect{ case List(x,y,z) => (x,y,z) }
//--> tuples: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), ...
```

Comment: I noticed that and managed to work around it.  I like the collect though.

Answer (score 10):

I know you got the answer you wanted, but the technically correct answer is *no*. There's no general method that takes a list and returns tuples of variable arity because there's no way to represent that type signature in Scala at the present.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  For my purpose, Pablo's solution works fine for me, but it's always nice to get more insight.